# Maven dependency doesn't find classes in default package

Tags: java, maven

There is something I don't understand with maven and I didn't find any answer out there. So I ask it here, hoping to get an answer.
I added a jar as a maven dependency for a project as system scope.
When I run `analyze-only` goal on dependency plugin, it does find it. But whenever I want to use classes located in default package in this jar, it won't compile.
I did the same with a jar from same provider with same classes but this time located in one package other than default and it compiles.
Is there something obvious I missed or has someone already encountered the same problem ?

It is not worth posting the code as I just try to import one of the class of system dependency.
My POM (system dependency)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>edu.algo</groupId>
  <artifactId>algorithms</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <properties>
    <lib.path>C:/lib</lib.path>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.princeton.cs</groupId>
        <artifactId>stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${lib.path}/stdlib/stdlib.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post your pom.xml and code so that others can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to bother you guys and thanks for your help.
I found the answer to my question and it has nothing to do with maven. You just cannot import classes in default package from named package for java versions above 1.4, I was using 1.7 version for compilation.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4989710

Answer (score 1):

Have you supplied the JAR it's looking for?  It sounds like it can't find the JAR against which to compile against.

Have you read this?

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dependency+Scopes

It states:

> system: This dependency is required in some phase of your project's
>   lifecycle, but is system-specific. Use of this scope is discouraged:
>   This is considered an "advanced" kind of feature and should only be
>   used when you truly understand all the ramifications of its use, which
>   can be extremely hard if not actually impossible to quantify. This
>   scope by definition renders your build non-portable. It may be
>   necessarry in certain edge cases. The system scope includes the
>    element which points to the physical location of this
>   dependency on the local machine. It is thus used to refer to some
>   artifact expected to be present on the given local machine an not in a
>   repository; and whose path may vary machine-to-machine. The systemPath
>   element can refer to environment variables in its path: ${JAVA_HOME}
>   for instance.

So, unless you have a solid reason for using this, maybe it's better to deploy the artifact into the repository and reference it like any other artifact?

Comment: I already read this but thanks for reminding us this. I did supply the jar because maven resolves the dependency. I first installed the jar in my local repo but then deleted it when I saw I can't use classes in default package. Then I didn't reinstall it as I was doing some experiments and because this project will never be deployed in any environment but my personal computer :).

Comment: So, you can't see the classes in both the methods used to add it to the classpath.  It sounds like it might be more an issue around the JAR and not the way Maven adds it to the classpath.  Perhaps the classes are not defined as public classes?  You could ensure it's finding it by using the dependency:tree goal, which will list all of the dependencies.  That will just confirm that the JAR is being picked up.

Comment: All classes I want to use are public and I already run by the way dependency:tree, it lists the depedency I need. So JAR is picked up but classes are not visible unless these classes are in a package. I added as experiment dependency with a different version of the same JAR. This JAR has all classes located in a package other than default. In this case, classes are available at compile time.

Comment: Weird, I've never seen that before.  It's still not clear to me if this is a problem with Maven and it's classpath generation or the java compiler.  It sounds like the correct JAR file is being included, and that's all that Maven is doing.

Comment: You are right, it has nothing to do with Maven finally. I found an answer, just below, just after answering your last-but-one comment. Thanks for your help.